# How to recognize a bot in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to record visits to my site, but I keep getting crawlers accidentally setting off my code. Is there any way in rails controllers to determine whether a user is a bot such as googlebot, etc?

Comment: If this is casual,  then you can inspect the user agent string, or create a valid robots.txt.  If this is security, then the bot can easily lie about it being a bot.  You can also require authentication for stuff you don't want to be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check HTTP headers, particularly the user agent string.

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Googlebot/

Most friendly bots have "bot" in their user agent.

Another suggestion is to use something like Google Analytics to track your visits. It's way better than implementing your own.

Comment: any ideas how i could do this in routes.rb?

Comment: routes.rb is only for configuring the routing. You should just add a method with before_filter in your ApplicationController to check the user agent for every call and act accordingly.